# Proof that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for negative $x$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

On Wikipedia, there is a [proof that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function).

If $t_n=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$, then we get
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}t_n\le e^x\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}t_n$$
so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=e^x$.

Then it says

> This equivalence can be extended to the negative real numbers by noting
> $$\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)^n\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{r^2}{n^2}\right)^n$$
> and taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

But I don't understand how this process extends the equality to negative numbers. If I multiply the equality by $\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$, I get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^n=1$$
but why should this prove anything about $e^x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x>0$. We have
$$
e^x \cdot \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 + \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 - \frac{{x^2 }}{{n^2 }}} \right)^n  = 1.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$, we get
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n  = e^{ - x} .
$$

Comment: This shows that if we define $e^x$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for all real $x$, then $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for all real $x$. Out of curiosity: if we first define $e^x$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ for all real $x$, then how can it be shown that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for all real $x$? I am able to prove it only for $x\ge 0$ this way.

Comment: Once you have it for $x>0$, you can note that $$
e^x \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - x)^n }}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {( - 1)^k \binom{n}{k}} } \right)\frac{{x^n }}{{n!}}}  = 1,
$$ with $x>0$.